# Mesh is inconsistent and different color

Tags: vertices, normals

[image]**Hi,i'm confused why this happened to me, i tried to click CTRL+N and nothing happened? i tried to delete it and merge it again and the mesh still inconsistent. What should i do now?**

Comment: Recalculate normals (outside) is `Shift + N`, not `Ctrl` - is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: yes but i change the keybind

Comment: you can find these functions in the header menu > Mesh > Normals. If it still doesn't work, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/